# How to sum results obtained with VLOOKUP and IMPORTRANGE in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, split, formula, flatten, google-query-language

I'm currently obtaining the result with the formula below, which was nicely provided by player0, but the challenge now is to obtain not only the figure found, but a sum, since the occurrences in the "database" may be multiple.

```
=Arrayformula(if(A9:A="";;IFNA(vlookup(A9:A&D9:D&"Expedição"&"Costura";
{IMPORTRANGE("fileId";"Produção!F2:F")&
IMPORTRANGE("fileId-1n3nQ";"Produção!H2:H")&
IMPORTRANGE("fileId-1n3nQ";"Produção!R2:R")&
IMPORTRANGE("fileId-1n3nQ";"Produção!B2:B")\
IMPORTRANGE("fileId-1n3nQ";"Produção!N2:N")};2;0))))
```

I have tried including sum in many places in the formula above, but with no success.

Here's a [file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU/edit?usp=sharing) with dummy data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how did you calculate 10 for row 4? A11 & A12 are not equal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ire9B.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A4:A="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(A4:A&" "&C4:C&" Expedição Costura ",
 QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(
 "1gh5w0czg2JuoA3i5wPu8_eOpC4Q4TXIRhmUrg53nKMU", "Data Origin!A2:R")}, 
 "select Col6,Col8,Col18,Col2,'×',Col14 where Col14>0 label '×'''", )),,9^9)), "×"), 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2>0 group by Col1"), 2, 0))))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything you couldn't do using these formulas, I wonder...

Comment: @onit try me :P ofc there is some stuff that needs to be done via script coz formulae cant handle certain actions

Comment: F'ing impressive!

Comment: @onit there are always multiple solutions like for example: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72297009/5632629